# Тест пропорций power.prop.test (достоверно ли значение конверсии)

Tags: r, статистика, rstudio

Столкнулся с задачей рассчитать стат.значимость значения конверсии по источникам трафика на сайте. 
Для расчета использовал функцию `power.prop.test ()`

Всего сеансов по всем источникам - 15367932

Суммарное число конверсий по всем источникам - 52482

CV = 0,3415%

Дано:

**Источник 1:**
1451587 - 8251 - cv=0,5684%

**Источник 2:**
2873 - 16 - cv=0,5569%

```
power.prop.test(p1=52482/15367932, p2=8251/1451587, power=0.8, sig.level=0.05)

Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 13806.63
             p1 = 0.003415033
             p2 = 0.005684124
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group

power.prop.test(p1=52482/15367932, p2=16/2873, power=0.8, sig.level=0.05)

Two-sample comparison of proportions power calculation 

              n = 15127.93
             p1 = 0.003415033
             p2 = 0.005569092
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided

NOTE: n is number in *each* group
```

Вопросы:

1. Я правильно понимаю, что в **источнике 1** у меня все хорошо, а в **источнике 2** мне нужно `15127.93` сеансов, чтобы с 95% уверенностью доверять значению конверсии?
2. Можете пояснить по `power=0.8`, о чем он говорит (как правильно интерпретировать)? Что в 20% случаев я не найду значение CV которое хочу?

Comment: `power.prop.test` для расчёта мощности, стат. значимость можно получить с помощью `prop.test` или `chisq.test`. `prop.test` помимо стат. значимости также может вернуть доверительный интервал для пропорции.

Comment: Меня интересует, при каком числе сеансов, можно доверять конверсии в источнике (размер выборки)? 

С помощью `prop.test` я проверял гипотезу о том, значимо ли отличается конверсия в `N источнике`, от средней по всем. Использовал `2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction`

Answer (score 0):

power=0.8 - насколько я понимаю, это вероятность того, что различий между вариантами нет, если мы их не увидели.
то есть 20% вероятности того, что если различий не было видно, а они всё-таки есть.